# I have been trying to update my SSM agent. I'm running the command AWS updatessmagent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, powershell, windows-update

I have been trying to update my SSM agent. I'm running the command AWS updatessmagent. This is what I am getting.

```
PS C:\Windows\Temp> AWS-UpdateSSMAgent

AWS-UpdateSSMAgent : The term 'AWS-UpdateSSMAgent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1

AWS-UpdateSSMAgent
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AWS-UpdateSSMAgent:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

can anyone help.

Comment: I have edited your post to format it so it's legible. Previously it was very difficult to follow. Formatting instructions are available when you create a question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-win.html) for Windows, manual updates to SSM agent are done manually. It looks like the powershell commands are

```
Invoke-WebRequest `
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/windows_amd64/AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe `
-OutFile $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\SSMAgent_latest.exe

Start-Process `
  -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\SSMAgent_latest.exe `
  -ArgumentList "/S"

rm -Force $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\SSMAgent_latest.exe
```

You can also set up automatic SSM agent updates [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent-automatic-updates.html).

I suspect the command you ran was for Linux.